# Fixed SVG css-background slows Webkit and FF

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, svg

I've been experimenting with pretty complicated SVG backgrounds (via CSS, fixed, 100% size) and it makes both FF and Webkit based browsers slow to a crawl, to the point it's impossible to scroll.

Would you have any idea how to improve the speed of it?

I investigated a big PNG (slow to load, not as "smooth" as SVG) and Canvas without much success.

The site in question was [here](http://therapywarsaw.com/psychotherapists/). Now it incorporates canvas method.

All the elements on the site are vector-based so it can scale to whatever device there is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it seems that all popular browsers render page/scroll much faster when the complicated svg background is applied to an underlying canvas (or img) then if it was applied to the body element itself.

Still looking for suggestions how to make it work faster, but at least now it is usable.

Comment: Applied as a background is slow compared to using img whether you apply to the body or a div

Answer (score 2):

This background is very complicated to render on the fly, so I believe that SVG is not feasible. You will have to consider one of the following solutions:

- Use a pre-rendered background (i.e. a png background).
- Use a simpler SVG, with less elements. In your current background the browser will have to render each line individually.

Comment: Pre-rendered PNG is going to be HUGE :( and I can see no way to simplify the SVG file. Maybe there is an easy route with SVG to Canvas endering with js?  

BTW Surprisingly the IE9 has no problems with the complicated SVG and is pretty snappy.

Comment: So I put a <canvas> with a css SVG background and it's waaay faster.